# Why doesn't the Libreoffice icon appear on my launcher when running?

Tags: 11.10, launcher, libreoffice

When we run an application, its icon would appear on the launcher and so we can call it back after minimize it. Specially, a little triangle would keep appearing  near the icon, meaning this application is running now.

However, when I open a Libreoffice file, the revelance icon doesn't appear on the launcher! What's more, when I minimize Libreoffice, I couldn't find it even through "Alt+Tab". I've tried Libreoffice 3.4 and 3.3, but the problem exists all the same.

Look, here is Libreoffice Calc running, and no icon appears on the launcher. If I minimize it, it is impossible to call it back.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload them now? It's hard to tell what this question is about without screeshots. :)

Comment: It would also help if you told us the User Interface. Is it Unity 3D or 2D or Gnome shell.

Comment: Can you Upload them now?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, unity 3D. Only unity has launcher, gnome shell has no launcher

Comment: Thanks for adding a screenshot! In order to help you with this best, can you [join us in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1591/i-was-very-annoyed-why-libreoffice-icon-didnt-appear-on-my-launcher-when-running)? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [libreoffice application does not use unity launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67330/libreoffice-application-does-not-use-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 5):

You can use 
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to show all the windows on your desktop. The LibreCalc window will appear there.

(The <kbd>Super</kbd> key is often the Windows logo).

There is a problem, but this is a work-around.

Comment: I have the same problem and this workaround unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Logout, then log back in again using Unity 2D, then log back out and back in with 3D. Your problem should be solved.

Theories as to why it does this include.

- Unity 2D launcher config overwrote the Unity 3D config, thus "fixing" the configuration files.
- Unity 3D was having a bad day and needed a break.

Comment: I am having this same issue and tried your suggestion to no avail.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso tried a `unity --reset`? *note: that* **will** *reset your unity config*

Comment: This solution does not work.

Comment: @zoopster [At the time when I was attempting to debug it, this was the solution that worked for the OP.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2176092#2176092). If that isn't the correct solution, then I'm sorry - you must have a different problem, or the OP did something that I wasn't told about.

Comment: unity --reset works, but there is something in unity that is corrupting the configuration. There are several bugs opened in LP against it...seems the Unity team is trying to figure it out, but it is not reproducible with consistency.
@jrg I would imagine (but cannot confirm) that a switch might reset the config temporarily, but it's not a workable solution.

Comment: and I was right with unity --reset. It worked to reset things, but the icon went away within a minute or so afterwards.

Comment: Then I suggest that you file a bug on this.

Comment: There are bugs on this already jrg

Answer (score -1):

go to libre office,click on tools,then view then change icon style from (breeze dark) which was for my case to BREEZE..close and lauch to see if problem solved.