# gVim dissapears when minimized and no way to maximize again

Tags: unity, 11.10, gvim

I am using gVim, installed using apt-get, and whenever I minimize the window it gets lost. The program is executing because I can see it in the monitor, but there is no way to bring back the editor. In fact in the dock it never appears as if it had been open. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!  (Using Unity with Ubuntu Oneric Ocelot)

Comment: Is the icon still on the launcher?

Comment: Yes it is. But let's say gVim is closed. If I click on the icon it opens gVim and keeps on flashing forever and never gets the little arrow on the side that shows that the program is running. So if I minimize gVim and click on this icon again it opens a new gvim instance. Not the one I was working with.

Comment: In fact if I search for it after pressing the super key it won't come up.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66802/why-doesnt-the-libreoffice-icon-appear-on-my-launcher-when-running This did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided in [the referenced question](https://askubuntu.com/q/66802/29556) was to "Logout, then log back in again using Unity 2D, then log back out and back in with 3D. Your problem should be solved."

Thought other might appreciate having the answer right here.