# libreoffice application does not use unity launcher

Tags: unity, libreoffice

Please fine below the image.
[image]

In this, you may observe that though libre writer is up, unity launcher does not have blue arrow. And clicking on it, does not bring back the application window.

Any pointers. I am on 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/842566

It's pretty annoying, and in 11.10 you also can't switch to LibreOffice via alt-tab - it just doesn't show up. Installing "lo-menubar" doesn't necessarily help, and indeed it can make things worse, since when maximized LibreOffice applications won't show their own menu bar nor the global menu bar, making it impossible to even close the window without resorting to keyboard shortcuts.

You can restart Unity for a very temporary fix, but sooner rather than later it'll happen again, sometimes right away.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing this **bug** too. Just restart unity. Run the command `unity --replace`. This works for me every time.

Comment: Have you filed a report? It won't get fixed unless someone reports it and some of those bugs can be really difficult to find, so the more users report it, the easier it will become to hunt it down. If it isn't already reported, can you please do that and update your answer to contain a link to it?

Comment: how do you file a report?

Comment: Ask that as a separate question. It's a good one, and generically useful, so let's enable the community to provide some good answers. :)

Comment: I too have noticed "misbehavior" but it's hard to describe and to reproduce. For me, it's always been Writer. Never an issue with Calc. I don't use the rest. Is there a less formal place to write about what we feel is not behaving so that a proper report can be formulated, perhaps collecctively?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/libreoffice-ship-global-menu-default-11-10/), support for the global menubar (and I assume the Unity launcher goes along with that) was intentionally not put in for the 11.10 release, citing stability concerns.

You can install support separately via the `lo-menubar` package:
    sudo apt-get install lo-menubar

I installed the package and it seems to work great so far.

Comment: Installing lo-menubar can bring its own problems. Here's a list of bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lo-menubar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to install a newer version of **bamfdaemon**, **libbamf3-0** and **libbamf0**

1. Get the packages from
   https://launchpad.net/~unity-team/+archive/staging/+sourcepub/2124839/+listing-archive-extra
2. Install with `sudo dpkg -i <packages>`
3. Kill the bamfdaemon with `killall bamfdaemon`

Libreoffice now should show up in the Unity-Panel and in alt-tab.

---

*(Credits to https://bugs.launchpad.net/bamf/+bug/842566/comments/64)*