# LibreOffice problem integrating with Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, libreoffice

I have started noticing this problem a while back. Opening spreadsheets directly from Nautilus sometimes has different behaviors in Unity. This means that sometimes I see the icon pop in the launcher like in the image below:

[image: icon shows up ok]

Other times I have the default LibreOffice icon, even though I have a spreadsheet (LibreOffice Calc) open:

[image: default Icon for spreadsheet]

And finally the worst case is when I don't get any icon at all even though I have the spreadsheet open:

[image]

In this final case I don't even have the close/minimize/maximize window in the top left corner. I can only close it with ALT+F4.

Any idea why Unity would behave like this?

I don't see a special pattern for this occurrences. Happens apparently random for both .ods and .xls files.

Comment: This is a bug and already reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/862171

Comment: thx. Even though not the same, could be related

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the libreoffice icon appear on my launcher when running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66802/why-doesnt-the-libreoffice-icon-appear-on-my-launcher-when-running)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. After I installed the [lo-menubar](http://www.howtogeek.com/93212/add-global-menu-support-to-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-11-04-unity/) (see synaptic) i haven't seen this issue (to be sure I will need to test longer). I'm wondering if you have the same experience.

Comment: I've read about it. It seems it's not fully functional yet, and the opinions are split. I may give it a try, just to see how it behaves (hope I can remove it safely afterwards if it generates problems). Actually I don't care much about the menu integration, for me the icons in the launcher are bugging me :)

Comment: Just a warning, lo-menubar will make your LibreOffice completely crash if you try to go into Page Preview.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 12.04 lo-menubar actually causes problems and removing it after upgrading from 11.10 has lead to the unity integration working much better.