# Why are menus in LibreOffice not rendering correctly and how can I fix this?

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

With most programs, context (right-click) menus and other menus have a shadow under them to indicate that they're separate from the rest of the program. This makes them easy to read. In LibreOffice, however, menus don't have shadows, and the top menu (file/edit/view, etc) is still in the program window itself, instead of in the global menu. How can I fix these problems?

This is on Kubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Which global menu are you referring to? Kubuntu does not have a global menu. Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: In the KDE netbook shell, there is a global menu.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice is not 100% Unity compliant.  I have asked a question in the past related to the LibreOffice icon and Unity launcher:

[libreoffice-problem-integrating-with-unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84108/libreoffice-problem-integrating-with-unity)

Maybe installing **lo-menubar** fixes some of your issues.

Cheers.

Comment: Installing lo-menubar didn't seem to work. It's not a problem integrating with unity, I don't think, but rather with kwin.

Answer (score 0):

Jon, I think changing the default font from "ubuntu" to "bitstream charter" (or any other small size fonts)in ubuntu tweak will solve the issue, because it worked for me. Give it a try. Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a programmer, you can’t fix these integration problems. These are known issues in LibreOffice. You could talk to a LibreOffice developer about this.