# LibreOffice (Writer, Calc, Impress) not appearing in launcher

Tags: 11.10, launcher, libreoffice

There is a problem with LibreOffice Calc, Impress and Writer (sometimes gedit too) that when I open a file the minimize, maximize and close buttons in the upper right corner are not displayed. In this case for Calc not only is this problem present but in the launcher the icon for Calc does not appear.

The only way right now I have found to at least get the icons in the top right corner when the problem arises is to open another windows and then go back to Calc. Still in this solution the launcher does not show a Calc icon.

How can I trace the problem or solve the problem at hand.

Already up to date with everything. The only 2 PPAs I am using are wine and chrome.

Here is a pic about the problem:

[image]

As you can see in the image there is no minimize,maximize and close buttons and the Calc program is not in the Launcher.

UPDATE - Updated question since it does appear in others as mentioned below. Just tested impress and writer when the problem happens and they too have it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the libreoffice icon appear on my launcher when running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66802/why-doesnt-the-libreoffice-icon-appear-on-my-launcher-when-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have this problem sometimes. A solution which works is to press Alt + F2 and type xkill. The mouse pointer will change to an "x".

Then press the super (windows) button on the keyboard to show the launcher and click on the launcher. Launcher will be killed and relaunched automatically.